# General formula for the frequency

Tags: orbital-motion, frequency

The orbital period of a satellite is the time it takes to complete an entire orbit around the celestial body around which it orbits. I know that the orbital period using the following formula:

$$T = \frac{T_{\text{tot}}}{n} \tag 1$$

where:

- $ T $ is the orbital period,
- $ T_{\text{tot}}$ is the total time taken to make a certain number of revolutions or cycles (in this case, one complete revolution),
- $ n $ is the number of revolutions or cycles completed in time $ T_{\text{tot}} $.

The $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$\boxed{\nu=\frac1T=\frac{n}{T_\text{tot}}} \tag 2$$

When we say frequency is the number of revolutions $n$ or cycles per second in school books has always written

$$\nu=\frac1T$$

> **Question**: Is it correct to write that the frequency $\nu$ is the number $n$ of revolutions $n$ or cycles per second, i.e.?
> $$\boxed{\nu=\frac{n}{T_{\text{tot}}}}\iff \frac1T=\frac{n}{T_{\text{tot}}}\implies (1) \, ?$$

Comment: What's your actual question ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas More in general is more correct to write that the frequence $ν$
 is the number $n$
 of revolutions $n$
 or cycles per second? There is written and it is more clear.

Comment: You mean, why frequency is not declared as $\nu= {n}/{t}$ ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Yes of course. I have not understood the reason of the downvote on a question more clear.

Comment: BTW, in orbital mechanics, the letter `n` is often used to represent [mean motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_motion), which is the mean angular velocity of the body, so it has units like degrees per second, or degrees per day.

Comment: What is the mean of BTW? However I have written that $ n $ is the number of revolutions or cycles completed in time $ T_{\text{tot}} $!

Comment: @PM2Ring Frequency/period is being used in many sections of Physics : Classical mechanics, statistical physics, quantum mechanics, astronomy, etc. So fetching one particular notation of $n$ from astronomy is not fair in the face of other Physics fields.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Thank you very much. Can you convert your comment "Because....." in an answer, please? I after print the question with the answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano BTW means By The Way. Yes, I understand that you are using `n` for the number of cycles. I was just pointing out that `n` is commonly used for the angular speed when discussing [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements).

Comment: @Sebastiano Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency can be expressed in both ways :
$$ \nu = \frac nt= \frac  {n}{nT} \equiv \frac 1T$$
but... Physics tends to give minimal, self-sufficient and non-redundant *definitions*. Adding factor $n$
in numerator and denominator does not change anything and makes equation actually more cryptic, since you can add meaningless factors to all equations (which does not change mathematical identity), like to say not $F=ma$, but $kF+b=kma+b$, but in this way we will actually spoil the main meaning of equation with unnecessary factors.

In addition, if you want to know number of revolutions per custom time interval, you just calculate $n=t/T \equiv t~\nu $. Hence from a minimal equation definition we can extract all information we need.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, especially depending on what data one has access to, it may make sense to use a relation such as $\nu={n\over T_{\text{tot}}}$ to calculate the frequency for a given harmonic motion. However, it is not "*more correct*" to write it in that form over the usual form, which is the *definition* of frequency:
$$\nu={1\over T}.$$